# Finder doesn't work since Yosemite

Tags: finder, macos, performance

Has anyone experienced any issues with using finder since updating to Yosemite?

Since updating, I can't open finder at all. I click on the icon and the pc just hangs up and in activity monitor, finder is just (not responding).

I've rebooted the machine, tried to open/locate a file in spotlight search and when I find a file, it won't open.

Any help/thoughts what to do would be appreciated.

Comment: Restart in Safe mode to see if that fixes it.

Answer (score 4):

This fix from Reddit worked perfectly for me!!

http://www.reddit.com/r/osx/comments/2jtikj/finder_not_responding_new_yosemite_install/

You can most likely fix the issue by clearing out Finder's saved state, caches, and/or settings.

Use Spotlight (the search icon in the far right of the menu bar) to find and open the "Terminal" application. Triple-click the following line in order to copy and paste it into Terminal's window:

```
rm -fR ~/Library/Saved\ Application\ State/com.apple.finder.savedState ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.finder; killall Finder
```

If it still doesn't work, try this one:

```
mv ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.finder{,.backup}.plist; killall Finder
```

Answer (score 1):

After Yosemite upgrade the finder crashes every time I drag and drop a file to a folder in the finder. It basically freezes and 'floats' the file icon until I force quit finder.

I tried quitting the Dropbox finder extension but it didn't work for me (you must quit Dropbox app first or the finder extension will auto relaunch). So I looked at the console errors right after a drag and drop crash and noticed a trail app I had trialed called Intego VirusBarrier that was causing the issue. After an uninstall and restart the finder worked as expected in Mac OSX 10.10.

Comment: Ah, it's been a while since I've heard the word "Intego." A year or so ago, the VirusBarrier trial broke my computer to the point of warranting a call to AppleCare. I had to boot in Safe Mode in order to uninstall the apps before they could automatically launch and wreak their computer-crashing havoc.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to check is the Extensions preference pane in System Preferences. Check whether there are any extensions listed for Finder. If so try disabling them by unticking the box beside them and seeing if the Finder behaves any better then.

[image: System Preferences showing Dropbox extension to Finder]

Another thing to check is Console. It can be a bit daunting at first but filter it to Finder related log entries and it might point you in the right direction (funnily enough I just discovered I have a problem when taking a screenshot for this answer).

[image: Console showing Finder log entries]

Answer (score 0):

In my case it seemed that a network drive (WDMyCloud via WdQuickView app) caused the Spinning wheel in Finder (Console showed a lock held exclusively for too long); disconnecting it solved this.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue. For me, the solve was to first turn off Wi-Fi (somehow Finder actually allowed that single action), connect an ethernet cable, then reboot the machine. Immediately after booting up, I quit the Dropbox app, then unchecked Dropbox in System Prefs › Extensions.

Seems to have resolved the issue for now.

Answer (score 0):

reenabling Finder icons solved this for me

Comment: Can You describe in more details what exactly You have done? This is very low quality answer, so please fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok all, I had all the issues listed above & just wanted to toss it out the window. It would crash every 5 minutes & had the constant beach ball. I would have Terminal open & Finder was always 'not responding'. My iMac had 24gig ram, which is way more than the standard 8 it ships with. Well, all my issues went away when I maxed it out with 32gig. Hope it helps you all

Answer (score 0):

You can usually fix most finder problems by force quitting it and relaunching it.

http://applemacosx.com/2015/09/30/what-to-do-when-mac-finder-is-not-responding/

If that doesn't work I recommend you do what Buscar said to do and reset the Finder's default state.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue in OS X 10.9.5

After trying aaaall proposals I found in different forums and websites, the one that seems to work is the one suggested [here](http://www.brandonmartinez.com/2011/11/26/resolve-a-frozen-finder-in-os-x-lion/):

> **Booting into “safe mode,” opening the Finder, poking around, and
>   restarting.**

Steps are:

> 1. Restart your Mac.
> 2. As soon as the grey boot screen appears (or
>      slightly before), press and hold shift on your keyboard.
> 3. Once you see a progress indicator, let go of shift.
> 4. Once your Mac boots, you’ll have to login to your account (auto-login is disabled).
> 5. Open the Finder. Navigate through a few folders.
> 6. Restart normally

---

*Edit:*

Just for extra info: after fixing this, Finder was not freezing anymore, but it started relaunching every minute or so. Also very annoying.

Solution for this was to **de-couple Google-Drive**, as suggested in [this thread](http://forums.macrumors.com/threads/finder-keeps-crashing-and-reloading.193521/), post #7.

Answer (score -3):

Turn off Wifi
Reboot
Works very well