# How to find out why finder hangs when "as List" / "as Columns" / "as Cover Flow" on Yosemite

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, finder, homebrew

After a while, `View` -> `as List` and `View` -> `as Columns` and `View` -> `as Cover Flow` stop working: the Finder window will not update at all, or - for the `Cover Flow` the "selection" part will not show a selection but the `Cover Flow` itself will follow selection changes.

A temporary workaround is the solution at [Finder doesn't work since Yosemite](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/153260/finder-doesnt-work-since-yosemite/186055#186055)

But after a while, the issue starts to appear again.

Obviously something is interfering with Finder, but I've no idea where and how to get started, so:

*How can I narrow this down to a cause?*

I run a late 2013 Retina MacBook Pro with Yosemite (10.9.5) and a truckload of stuff including:

- SwitchResX (I've disabled the extensions: no change in behaviour)
- DropBox
- Google Drive
- brew
- gfxCardStatus
- TunnelBlick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is/was Google Drive. As of early October they silently released a new version 1.32 that <s>might have solved the problem but since that one hasn't reached my system yet I will get back to it later</s> has solved the problem. All the versions since then work fine, including the new ["Backup and Sync"](https://www.google.com/drive/download/backup-and-sync/).

Version 1.31 intermittently fails only on Mac OS X Mavericks (10.9.5) but disabling the visual notifications solves it; upgrading to a newer version also solves the problem.

Some references:

- others having the same issue: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/TeXBYS4qH0g and https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/rzdrkYWlgGc
- solving on Mavericks: https://www.maketecheasier.com/fix-google-drive-crashing-finder-in-mavericks/
- version 1.32: http://www.macworld.co.uk/download/internet-tools/google-drive-13233635836-3328202/